# Проблема с POST запросом в swift 4

Tags: json, ios, xcode, post, swift4

Делаю свое первое приложение для iPhone . Проблемный код ниже

```
@IBAction func searchCarNumberPost(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let urlApiUkraine = URL(string: "ссылка удалена") else {return}
    var parametrs = "ai1788hi"
    var request = URLRequest(url: urlApiUkraine)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parametrs, options: []) else {return}
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
            }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }.resume()
```

При обработке мне выдает ошибку и приложение зависает. 
Есть подозрение что проблема в строке

```
var parametrs = "ai1788hi"
```

и в ее связи с

```
guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parametrs, options: [])
```

Как я уже разобрался мне должен вернуться не json пакет и обычного print(data) хватило бы, но до расшифровки дело так и не доход по сути. в сеть запрос даже не уходит. 
перечитал уже кучу постов но с решением моей проблемы так и не нашел. 
Может кто-то подсказать в чем проблема и в какую сторону мне смотреть?

Comment: Добавьте что должно уходить.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема действительно в строке `var parametrs = "ai1788hi"`

Т.к. происходит вызов метода `withJSONObject:` необходимо туда передавать JSON.

В Swift это формат [:]

Crash происходит в строке:

`guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parametrs, options: []) else {return}`

Необходимо формировать структуру типа `key-value` - словарь.

`var parametrs = ["key": "value"]`